# How to get the exact date with months?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

In my project, I put the date like **11/27/2020** and period for next **exam 6 months** OR **3 months**

How can I get the exact date?

I use date calculating in my SQL with days or years working fine but with months no I tried 183 days and 182 days but it doesn't get The exact date.

I can deal with commands in SQL or the ASP.NET MVC controller but I miss the exact calculation.

Even if there is a good adding from NuGet packages can do that.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you provide more details, what you have in your code, and the desired result?

Comment: for example if last exam was in 11/27/2020 in text box I put next one will be after 6 months then new date text box will be shown 05/27/2021 I want to be auto calculate

Comment: It sounds your question is related to the UI, but in the C# it is easy to do that with this statement new DateTime(2020, 11, 27).AddMonths(6)

Comment: Please provide more details about this question. Basically in C# you can add month with the AddMonth() method.and in sql you can use DATEADD(MONTH,6,'11/27/2020')

Comment: Emin and Hardik thanks for reply I will try that and let you know.

Comment: It works fine thank you very much